# Jquery not working inside PUG. Isn't recognising $ sign even though I have included jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I have put my jquery code inside pug template but it is not running. I am trying to run jQuery function but I am getting the following error even though I have included the jQuery file too: -

```
 40|                 P   

    41|                     script(type="text/javascript")

  > 42|                        -  $("#image-drop-area").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" })


$ is not a function
```

Here is my pug template: -

```
        p
            label(for="tags") Tags (Seperated by comma): 
            input(type="text" name="tags" id="tags" required autofocus)

        P   
            script(type="text/javascript")
               -  $("#image-drop-area").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is to process the javascript/jquery line in the pug file (with `-`). Try this instead:

```
script(type="text/javascript").
  $("#image-drop-area").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" })
```

Note the dot at the end: `script(type="text/javascript").`. It writes the following block as plain text into the `script` tag.

[Block in a Tag](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html)

Comment: Is there a way to use jQuery AND have Pug minify it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69944537/how-can-i-have-minify-uglify-inline-javascript-using-pug